# Conan building cpp project using gcc on windows

Tags: c++, boost, conan

I have been having a hard time getting conan to build a project using gcc on my windows machine.

This is what I currently have in my conan profile.

```
toolchain=F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin
target_host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
cc_compiler=gcc
cxx_compiler=g++

[env]
CONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$toolchain
CHOST=$target_host
AR=$target_host-ar
AS=$target_host-as
RANLIB=$target_host-ranlib
CC=$target_host-$cc_compiler
CXX=$target_host-$cxx_compiler
STRIP=$target_host-strip
RC=$target_host-windres


[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=gcc
build_type=Release
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.version=11.2
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CC=F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin/gcc
CXX=F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin/g++
```

Prior to trying out ninja and conan. I have been compile using gcc without an issue with either clion or vs code.

Now, this simply doesnt work. Looking from the error and my setup, what I am missing?

The error I am getting is bellow..

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target zlibstatic
[100%] Built target zlibstatic
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/d846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14/lib/libzlibstatic.a
-- Installing: C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/d846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14/include/zconf.h
-- Installing: C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/d846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14/include/zlib.h
zlib/1.2.11 package(): Packaged 2 '.h' files: zconf.h, zlib.h
zlib/1.2.11 package(): Packaged 1 '.a' file: libzlib.a
zlib/1.2.11 package(): Packaged 1 file: LICENSE
zlib/1.2.11: Package 'd846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14' created
zlib/1.2.11: Created package revision 281d3c2cde56d66bef4dac5d2b0c380d
boost/1.77.0: Applying build-requirement: b2/4.7.1
Downloading conan_sources.tgz
boost/1.77.0: Configuring sources in C:\.conan\be116f\1

boost/1.77.0: Building your package in C:\.conan\b56bd8\1
boost/1.77.0: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
boost/1.77.0: Aggregating env generators
boost/1.77.0: Calling build()
notice: found boost-build.jam at C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/boost-build.jam
notice: loading B2 from C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/bootstrap.jam
warning: mismatched versions of B2 engine and core
warning: B2 engine (b2.exe) is 4.7.1
warning: B2 core (at C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src) is 4.6-git
notice: Searching 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/util' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/contrib' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/kernel' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/util' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/build' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/tools' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/contrib' 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build/src/.'.
notice: Loading explicitly specified user configuration file:
    C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build\user-config.jam
notice: Searching 'C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build'.
notice: [zlib] Using pre-installed library
notice: [zlib] Condition
notice: [bzip2] Using pre-installed library
notice: [bzip2] Condition
notice: will use 'F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin/g++' for gcc, condition <toolset>gcc-11
notice: using gcc libraries :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib32 F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib64
notice: using gcc archiver :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ar.exe
notice: using gcc ranlib :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ranlib.exe
notice: using rc compiler :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:\tools\msys2\mingw64\bin\windres.exe
notice: [zlib] zlib is already configured
notice: [bzip2] bzip is already configured
notice: iostreams: not using lzma compression
notice: iostreams: not using zstd compression
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "python"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'DIR /-C /A:S "F:\tools\msys2\mingw64\bin\python.exe" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'python -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "python"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "F:/tools/msys2/mingw64\Include"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "F:/tools/msys2/mingw64\libs"
notice: [python-cfg]   DLL search path: "F:/tools/msys2/mingw64"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking for NumPy...
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'python -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())"'
notice: [python-cfg] NumPy disabled. Reason:
notice: [python-cfg]   python -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())" aborted with
notice: [python-cfg]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit [1]
    - default architecture     : x86 [1]
    - compiler supports SSE2   : yes [2]
    - compiler supports SSE4.1 : yes [2]
    - has synchronization.lib  : yes [2]
    - has std::atomic_ref      : yes [2]
    - has statx                : no [2]
    - has statx syscall        : no [2]
    - has BCrypt API           : yes [2]
    - has init_priority attribute : yes [2]
    - has stat::st_blksize     : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtim        : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no [2]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes [2]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : yes [2]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes [2]
    - cxx11_final              : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes [2]
    - cxx11_lambdas            : yes [2]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : yes [2]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : yes [2]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes [2]
    - cxx11_template_aliases   : yes [2]
    - cxx11_thread_local       : yes [2]
    - cxx11_variadic_templates : yes [2]
    - has_icu builds           : no [2]
    - zlib                     : yes [3]
    - bzip2                    : yes [3]
    - cxx11_decltype           : yes [2]
    - cxx11_basic_alignas      : yes [2]
    - native atomic int32 supported : yes [2]
    - has message compiler     : no [2]
    - native syslog supported  : no [2]
    - pthread supports robust mutexes : no [2]
    - compiler supports SSSE3  : yes [2]
    - compiler supports AVX2   : yes [2]
    - gcc visibility           : yes [2]
    - sfinae_expr              : yes [2]
    - cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes [2]
    - cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_array          : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes [2]
    - cxx11_allocator          : yes [2]
    - cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes [2]
    - gcc visibility           : yes [4]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : yes [4]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes [4]
    - sfinae_expr              : yes [4]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes [4]
    - cxx11_lambdas            : yes [4]
    - cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes [4]
    - cxx11_thread_local       : yes [4]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : yes [4]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : yes [4]
    - cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes [4]
    - cxx11_decltype           : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_array          : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes [4]
    - cxx11_allocator          : yes [4]
    - cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes [4]
    - long double support      : yes [4]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : yes [2]
    - std::fstream is moveable and swappable : yes [2]
    - Has Large File Support   : yes [2]
    - Has attribute init_priority : yes [2]
    - libbacktrace builds      : no [2]
    - libbacktrace builds      : no [5]
    - addr2line builds         : no [2]
    - addr2line builds         : no [5]
    - WinDbg builds            : yes [2]
    - WinDbg builds            : yes [5]
    - WinDbgCached builds      : yes [2]
    - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : yes [2]

[1] gcc-11
[2] gcc-11/rls/bst.l-off/bst.l-off/lnk-sttc/nm-on/pythn-3.9/thrdp-wn32/thrd-mlt/vsblt-hdn
[3] lnk-sttc
[4] gcc-11/rls/bst.l-off/bst.l-off/lnk-sttc/nm-on/pch-off/pythn-3.9/thrdp-wn32/thrd-mlt/vsblt-hdn
[5] gcc-11/rls/bst.l-off/bst.l-off/bld-no/lnk-sttc/nm-on/pythn-3.9/thrdp-wn32/thrd-mlt/vsblt-hdn

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : building
    - chrono                   : building
    - container                : building
    - context                  : building
    - contract                 : building
    - coroutine                : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - fiber                    : building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - headers                  : not building
    - iostreams                : building
    - json                     : building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - nowide                   : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - stacktrace               : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - type_erasure             : building
    - wave                     : building

...failed updating 2 targets...
boost/1.77.0:
WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/* thread_local */' in 'C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\boost\stacktrace\detail\libbacktrace_impls.hpp' file.
WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/* static __thread */' in 'C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\boost\stacktrace\detail\libbacktrace_impls.hpp' file.
boost/1.77.0: WARN: Patching user-config.jam
boost/1.77.0: WARN:
using zlib : 1.2.11 : <include>"C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/d846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14/include" <search>"C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/d846067d59c3b90a9880f5caaf4b040d4f30bf14/lib" <name>zlib ;
using bzip2 : 1.0.8 : <include>"C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/_/_/package/07f1212a082286f0a4860450e86ce4aca0317e05/include" <search>"C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/_/_/package/07f1212a082286f0a4860450e86ce4aca0317e05/lib" <name>bz2 ;
using "gcc" :  :  F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin/g++ :
 ;
boost/1.77.0: WARN: b2.exe -q numa=on target-os=windows architecture=x86 address-model=64 binary-format=pe abi=ms --layout=system --user-config=C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build\user-config.jam -sNO_ZLIB=0 -sNO_BZIP2=0 -sNO_LZMA=1 -sNO_ZSTD=1 boost.locale.icu=off --disable-icu boost.locale.iconv=off --disable-iconv threading=multi visibility=hidden link=static variant=release --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-container --with-context --with-contract --with-coroutine --with-date_time --with-exception --with-fiber --with-filesystem --with-graph --with-iostreams --with-json --with-locale --with-log --with-math --with-nowide --with-program_options --with-random --with-regex --with-serialization --with-stacktrace --with-system --with-test --with-thread --with-timer --with-type_erasure --with-wave toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=c++2a define=_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 pch=on  cxxflags="-fPIC" install --prefix=C:\.conan\bbf755\1 -j12 --abbreviate-paths -d0 --debug-configuration --build-dir="C:\.conan\b56bd8\1"
boost/1.77.0: ERROR: Package '6c2d1fff171f1115008f92b1231de7ab8ab916fc' build failed
boost/1.77.0: WARN: Build folder C:\.conan\b56bd8\1
ERROR: boost/1.77.0: Error in build() method, line 837
        self.run(full_command, run_environment=True)
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing b2.exe -q numa=on target-os=windows architecture=x86 address-model=64 binary-format=pe abi=ms --layout=system --user-config=C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build\user-config.jam -sNO_ZLIB=0 -sNO_BZIP2=0 -sNO_LZMA=1 -sNO_ZSTD=1 boost.locale.icu=off --disable-icu boost.locale.iconv=off --disable-iconv threading=multi visibility=hidden link=static variant=release --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-container --with-context --with-contract --with-coroutine --with-date_time --with-exception --with-fiber --with-filesystem --with-graph --with-iostreams --with-json --with-locale --with-log --with-math --with-nowide --with-program_options --with-random --with-regex --with-serialization --with-stacktrace --with-system --with-test --with-thread --with-timer --with-type_erasure --with-wave toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=c++2a define=_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 pch=on  cxxflags="-fPIC" install --prefix=C:\.conan\bbf755\1 -j12 --abbreviate-paths -d0 --debug-configuration --build-dir="C:\.conan\b56bd8\1"
```

When I run a failing b2 command manually from terminal I get the following output (error)

```
notice: found boost-build.jam at C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel/boost-build.jam
notice: loading B2 from C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel/bootstrap.jam
notice: Searching 'C:\WINDOWS' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/util' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/build' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/tools' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/contrib' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in 'C:\WINDOWS' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:\Users\Ruslan' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/kernel' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/util' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/build' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/tools' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/contrib' 'C:/Users/Ruslan/.conan/data/b2/4.7.1/_/_/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/bin/.b2/.'.
notice: Loading explicitly specified user configuration file:
    C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build\user-config.jam
notice: Searching 'C:\.conan\be116f\1\source_subfolder\tools\build' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from 'C:/.conan/be116f/1/source_subfolder/tools/build'.
notice: [zlib] Using pre-installed library
notice: [zlib] Condition
notice: [bzip2] Using pre-installed library
notice: [bzip2] Condition
notice: will use 'F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin/g++' for gcc, condition <toolset>gcc-11
notice: using gcc libraries :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/bin F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib32 F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/lib64
notice: using gcc archiver :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:/tools/msys2/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ar.exe
notice: using rc compiler :: <toolset>gcc-11 :: F:\tools\msys2\mingw64\bin\windres.exe
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
notice: could not find main target install
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
error: Project target requested but not yet assigned for module 'Jamfile<C:\Users\Ruslan\.conan\data\b2\4.7.1\_\_\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\bin>'.
```

I not sure what is meant by the *project target not being assigned*?

Comment: try running the failing command manually to see if you get more information

Comment: Which command would that be, if you dont mind pointing out?

Comment: `b2.exe -q numa=on.....`

Comment: I have updated with the log from running the b2 command.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Do you know what this b2 error is about? Any suggestions on what I should try ?